# How does Rey actually get to Exegol?

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

In *Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker*, Rey destroys Kylo Ren's TIE fighter, which has the Sith Wayfinder in it, and Kylo gets a new one from the First Order.

1. How did it survive her fire when she burnt the fighter?
2. How was the Wayfinder actually in it?

Comment: How does Han Solo actually get to Endor? ‘_e walks._

Answer (score 6):

If I'm remembering the sequence of events correctly, Rey lands Ren's TIE on Ahch-To and burns it, intending to go into self-exile.  Luke's Force ghost shows up and convinces her not to, so she pulls the Sith Wayfinder out of the wreckage of the TIE fighter (it's apparently immune to fire) and Luke dredges up his old X-Wing; Rey takes the X-Wing and the Sith Wayfinder and flies to Exegol.

So, your questions in order:

0. In Luke's old (apparently waterproof) X-Wing.
1. It's apparently fireproof.
2. The Wayfinder was in the TIE fighter when she stole it from Ren, and she hadn't removed it.

Note that there appears to be some confusion about Ren's TIE fighter; he loses one on Pasaana, but he arrives on Kef Bir in another one.  This last one must have the Sith Wayfinder, since he tells Rey "The only way you’re getting to Exegol is with me."  And it's quite clear in the movie that she removes the distinctive pyramidal shape of a Sith Wayfinder from the smoking wreckage of the TIE fighter just before Luke pulls his X-Wing from the ocean.

Comment: Wasn't Kylo's Tie Fighter with the wayfinder destroyed when chasing Rey on the desert planet (the trailer scene)? Seems like that one is long gone.

Comment: There were only 2.  Ren's must have survived the crash of Ren's TIE in the desert, just like Ren himself.  If it had been destroyed, Ren wouldn't have destroyed the other one (which would be the last, only, one) when Rey found it on Kef Bir.  Ren says "The only way you’re getting to Exegol is with me." so he _must_ still have had a wayfinder to get back there.

Answer (score 1):

1. Kylo's wayfinder was fireproof, as described in the novelization (emphasis added):

> Her heart sunk. By trying to do the right thing, she had ruined everything. "I can't get there," she said. "I don't have the wayfinder. I destroyed Ren's ship."
>
> The Jedi Master's smile held so much fondness it made her heart ache. "You have everything you need," he said gently.
>
> [...]
>
> The TIE was now a smoldering wreck. A few porgs huddled nearby, as close to the warmth of the dying fire as they dared.
>
> Something twinged inside her, called to her, and she stepped forward. A night drizzle had cooled the wreckage. Following her instincts, she reached down and shoved the detritus aside.
>
> **A wayfinder sat there, smokeless and pristine. *Vader's* wayfinder.**
>
> Rey whispered, "Two were made..."
>
> (source: *The Rise of Skywalker: Expanded Edition*, page 189)

2. This also confirms that this was, specifically, Vader's wayfinder, which Kylo Ren recovers from Mustafar at the beginning of the movie. It apparently comes as a surprise to Rey that the wayfinder was in the TIE at all, so Kylo must have taken it from his first crashed TIE and left it in his second TIE on Kef Bir, which is the one that Rey stole.